# Does a web cracker need reading perrmission to destroy a UNIX server

Tags: security, unix, cgi, cracking

In UNIX, if I give a website member indirect permission to write to a file, read from the file, but through a `cgi`, what are the security risks?

like so:

[image: schematic]

As you can see, only the cgi has permission to read and write to the file.
It would seem that this would prevent security problems.

OR AM I FOOLING MYSELF?

Edit:

here's how it works:
1. the user enters there info in a simple `<form>`.
2. the user sends the `<form>` to the cgi.
3. the cgi writes the `<form>` info to the file.

I guess my main worry is the user embedding destructive exes in the file.
However they don't have *DIRECT* permission to r/w the file.

also...
... it is this and only this file that the user can indirectly write to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security implications depend on what affect viewing/editing said file has. If the user is able to view `/etc/shadow` (which contains password hashes), then they would be able to attempt to bruteforce user passwords. If they are able to access any configuration files as well, it may expose login details and other sensitive information.

If properly implemented, this system can be secure, but it would be fighting and uphill battle, and there are many other solutions that would probably suit your needs better.

Comment: the user cannot view anything. It is the CGI that has file r/w permission

Comment: Yes, I understood that, you just need to ensure that there is no way for the user to read/write a file they do not have permissions to. For example say they can read a file that is their username in a directory, but someone makes their username ../../../../../../../etc/shadow, they could potentially read the password hash file.

Comment: sorry I didn't accept your answer earlier.. sorta got busy.